# Powershell. Merge contents of multiple folders into a single one

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, powershell-4.0

I have about one hundred subfolders in a folder; each contains images and videos:

```
ParentFolder
    - 010119Folder
        - pic.jpg
        - otherpic.jpg
        -- vid.mp4
    - 020119Folder
        - more_jpgs_and_mp4s.jpg
    - 030119Folder
        - etc.mp4
    - etc.
```

I would like to move all files to a single folder for example:

```
2019Folder
     - pic.jpg
     - otherpic.jpg
     - vid.mp4
     - more_jpgs_and_mp4s.jpg
     - etc.mp4
```

Any way to achieve this with Windows 10 powershell?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Also, are you doing this on Windows 10, or on a system with Windows PowerShell 4? Windows 10 ships with Windows PowerShell 5, and if you have been allowing updates to apply normally, you probably have Windows PowerShell 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way, but finally got this working:

Run powershell

```
cd ParentFolder

$folders = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }

for ($i=0; $i -lt $folders.Count; $i++) {
    $curfolder = $folders[$i].FullName 
    cp -Path "$curfolder\*" - Destination c:\DestinationFolder\
}
```

Comment: Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination "c:\DestinationFolder"